# Do nothing inside else{} statement

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a script that sets the width of a div element as a percentage of its height, but I only want this script to run when the width of the viewport is greater than 800px. Here's my code, which works fine when the viewport is wider than 800px, but continues to run at resolutions less than 800px wide:

```
function main_set_width() {
    if ($(window).width() > 799) {
        var height = $('.main-set-width').height();
        $('.main-set-width').css('width',height * 1.2974);
    } else {
        return;
    };
};
```

Does anybody know what I can put in the else{} statement to prevent the script from running the stuff in the if{} statement?

Comment: This isn't exactly the answer to the question but this looks like a case where media queries might be the best solution. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries for more information on those.

Comment: [Can you reproduce the problem?](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, your `if` statement is wrong.

Try using `if( innerWidth > 799)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously setting the css width with jQuery INSIDE your function. So, you don't have to return anything in that case. You don't need an else statement at all. If the condition inside the "if" is not fulfilled, the function will not execute at at all, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to change element's height to something fluid after a certian screen size - id suggest using media-queries in that case

HTML

```
<div class="page">

    <div class="fluid-element-wrapper">
        <div class="fluid-element">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fluid-element-wrapper {
    width:30%;
    height:auto;
    padding-bottom:0;
    background:green;
}

@media ( max-width:799px ) {
    .fluid-element-wrapper {
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding-bottom:30%; /* or whatever the fluid height you'd want it to be */
    }

    .fluid-element {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/Rqs3C/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem not so long ago. You could try something like below:

```
function main_set_width() {
    if ($(window).width() > 799) {
        var height = $('.main-set-width').height();
        $('.main-set-width').css('width',height * 1.2974);
    } else {
        $('.main-set-width').css().remove();
    };
};
```